# What's the difference between "erroneous" and "wrong"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, adjectives

Are these words totally interchangeable?

> I made the [erroneous/wrong] decision.

Comment: I imagine that "wrong" in this context is in the sense of "incorrect" rather than "morally indefensible".

Comment: @Cyberherbalist & others: "Wrong" does not necessarily imply "moral" or "ethical". You dialed the wrong number there.

Answer (score 15):

'Erroneous' is typically used when you're talking about fact-based issues.   It means *incorrect* or *mistaken*.

> He made the erroneous assumption that the world was flat.

'Wrong' can be used in those situations too:

> He's wrong about how much water will fit in that cup.

But it has broader meaning to include things that are morally or ethically wrong, unfair, or unjust.

> Shoplifting is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: thank you for your answer. do you use the word "erroneous" in a common conversation?

Comment: Also, only *wrong* is normally used the thing being referenced is an *actual physical object or action*, as opposed to an abstract concept such as a *assumption, decision, choice*. So you can only ever *go through the **wrong door*** (not the *erroneous door*). But "word" is a somewhat slippery word, so you can (just about) *use **an** erroneous word*. Normally though, it would be ***the** wrong word* (just don't ask me why the indefinite/definite articles have to be switched around in the case of inappropriate/incorrect *words!* :)

Comment: I can't remember the last time I used it at all in a common conversation.  I've used "wrong" lots of times, however.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think there's a word missing in your first line: "only used", "used when"?? I can't work out whether you're saying *wrong* is or is not used with abstract concepts, but I think you *can* refer to a *wrong* **or** *erroneous* *assumption*.

Comment: @TrevorD: Ooops! Typo! I meant to say *only "wrong" is normally used **when** the thing being referenced is blah blah...*

Comment: Also, *wrong* is used as a predicate nominative referring to people, but *erroneous* is not.  "He was *wrong*!" is okay, but "He was *erroneous*!" is not.

Comment: Additionally, "wrong" can be more subjective than "erroneous".  If I say something is "erroneous", I better have proof.  But "wrong" could just be a matter of opinion.  (It isn't always, but it is a bit fuzzy.)

Comment: @Daiki, I certainly use _erroneous_ in conversation when the context is mathematical, scientific, or statistics. This doesn't have to be in a technical conversation; say, _The Romney campaign's reliance on low minority voter turnout was erroneous._ In this sentence, indeed, _wrong_ would be ambiguous: whether it was morally reprehensible, refuted by events, or both.

Answer (score 8):

They are not interchangeable.  Here's an example:

> I reviewed the erroneous article.

I reviewed the article; it contained an error.

> I reviewed the wrong article.

I was not supposed to review that article at all, but a different one.

Answer (score 4):

A number of dictionary definitions emphasise that the word "erroneous" is derived from the word "error":

> containing or characterized by error : mistaken <*erroneous* assumptions> 
>   (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/erroneous)
>
> **Definition:** mistaken, incorrect, or containing an error
>   **Tips:** Erroneous is related to the word error. Both words are derived from the Latin errare, “to wander, miss." If someone or something wanders off course, in error, it is erroneous. In business, you may garner more respect referring to an "erroneous transaction," than to a "mistake" or "mess-up."
>   **Usage Examples:**
>   The erroneous assumption by the marketing manager cost the company thousands of dollars. (mistaken, false)
>   My erroneous planning is to blame for our missed deadline. (incorrect, false)
>   Generally, newspapers will retract and apologize for erroneous headlines and statements. (incorrect, mistaken)
>   His erroneous statements caused me a lot of trouble and time proving that he was mistaken. (incorrect, false)
>   (http://vocabulary-vocabulary.com/dictionary/erroneous.php)
>
> containing or based on error; incorrect; mistaken.
>   *The police acted on an erroneous assumption that the killer was a male.*
>   *The scientists made an erroneous interpretation of their findings.*
>   (http://www.wordsmyth.net/?ent=erroneous)

I think this helps to differentiate between *erroneous* and *wrong* to some extent:

> *erroneous* clearly relates to an error, mistake, or inaccuracy.
>   Typical antonyms are: *correct*, *accurate*.
>
> *wrong* can carry the same meaning, but also has the meaning as the antonym of *right*, as in the [morally] right or wrong behaviour.